# In PHP how to use two headers Location

Tags: php, security, header, location, sms

```
<?php 
header("Location:http://www.perfectbulksms.in/Sendsmsapi.aspx
USERID=namePASSWORD=pass&SENDERID=id&TO=$phn&MESSAGE=$sms");
header("Location:password.php?msg=new");
?>
```

I want to send sms through php code. it is working fine but the problem is i have to use two headers one for the sms and another for to redirect my page on the location i want. but only the second one is working. and i also want to hide the detail of my sms code when it url in the tab. and want to use both sms and redirect. please help?????

Comment: Check the usage of if condition - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: better use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: Agreed with R andom above, if you want to do it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$pre = 'Dear%20Parents,YourPasswordis%20';
header("Location:http://www.perfectbulksms.in/Sendsmsapi.aspx
USERID=namePASSWORD=pass&SENDERID=id&TO=$phn&MESSAGE=$sms");
header("Location:password.php?msg=new");
?>
```

Thanks alot all i was using space instead of %20 thats why it is not working thanks @arun @chris @dass for telling curl option

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to send something, you could simply do:

```
<?php
file_get_contents("http://www.perfectbulksms.in/Sendsmsapi.aspx?USERID=name&PASSWORD=pass&SENDERID=id&TO=$phn&MESSAGE=$sms");
header("Location:password.php?msg=new");
?>
```

Not pretty, but it will do in a pinch.

Definitely should do this using curl(), however.

Comment: You need to fix the URL, it's missing the argument separators. I fixed it in my example above.

Answer (score 1):

`header("Location: ...");` is use to redirect user to another page. Think logically how can you redirect user on 2 pages at the same time.

As I can see you want to make an API Call to perfectbulksms.in to Send SMS 
I would highly suggest to use CURL to do so and then use header

```
    $ch = curl_init("http://www.perfectbulksms.in/Sendsmsapi.aspxUSERID=namePASSWORD=pass&SENDERID=id&TO=$phn&MESSAGE=$sms");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
header("Location:password.php?msg=new");
```

this is a basic example, Read more about CURL http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: no its not working.. its going to next header but sms is not going .. what to do with this $result variable

Comment: @YogeshArya have you corrected the mistakes in your URL?

Comment: $result variable contain the response from perfectbulksms.in (if any), try commenting //`header("Location:password.php?msg=new");` and echo result to debug what is the issue.

Comment: @dass are you talking about username password and id .Yes i corrected it. If there is any other mistake please tell me

Comment: Bad Request

HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed. This comes when i use echo option ... is it neccessary to close curl???   and it is giving me the paswword on echo

Comment: if you are getting Error 400 that mean there is some issue in url or data sent in url, you can check by opening the url in browser and check it